# "when I’m 100% confirm what to study" or "when I'm 100% confirmed what to study"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, spoken-english, conversation

> I’ll tell you when I’m 100% **confirm** what to study

Or:

> I’ll tell you when I'm 100% **confirmed** what to study

Which one is correct?

Comment: I'll tell you when I'm 100% sure what to study.

Comment: Please be more careful when you type out a question. Your original wording in your title did not 100% match the wording in your question. Moreover, don't ask "which one is correct" when one of your options has typos. My edits may have changed the original intent of your question; if that's the case, please edit it again to ask what you want to ask, but be more careful about wording your question such that anyone reading this can clearly understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Neither is correct because confirm or confirmed cannot be used in that way.  So it's hard to answer without understanding the actual issue you're trying to resolve.  Can you add some paraphrasing to better explain the intent of the question?

Comment: "Confirm" implies that you are verifying something with someone else.  Are you saying that a teacher or curriculum will specify what you will study and you need to verify the details?  Is the sentence about your planning to make a decision of what to study, and you aren't yet sure what your decision will be?  In that case, a word like "sure" would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll tell you when **I have 100% confirmed what I will study**.

This is the grammatically correct form of your sentence. 100% is an adverb in this case (meaning *entirely*) so it goes before the verb.

The final part of your sentence (*what to study*) made me think a bit. It sounded wrong to me, but I'm not sure why. Someone else might be able to provide some insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

To me none of the sentences seem natural. The usage of **confirm** in the sentence seems odd.

I would say something like

> I will tell you when I am 100% **confident/sure** what to study